# Is iOS non-consumable purchase tied with use account or device?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to make a non-consumable purchase system in iOS.

I have created two sandbox testing accounts :  User A and User B. Suppose User A purchases the product, deletes and reinstalls the app. When he restores, he gets the product as expected.

But suppose I logout of User A's account and login using User B's account **on the same device** and user B tries to restore. In this case, the expected behaviour is to get nothing, but he gets the products bought by user A.

I am using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`
for restoring purchases.
I cannot use `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:username]`as we do not have login system.

Extra info : Tested in Sandbox environment on real device with min iOS Version support : 8.0

Answer (score -1):

non-consumable IAP restore base on Account Apple ID not by Device. It's help user can restore IAP from the app on any devices.

And using [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; is work well for me.

Comment: Did you check on the same device with different accounts ? For me it's restoring the purchases by other accounts too .

Comment: IAP restore by Account not by same device. Maybe the problem is your code. I advice you read this tuts:  [IAP Tuts](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)

Comment: IAPs restore by account ,I know and that is happening. Did you read the question ? Have you checked on the same device with different accounts. I call the same ` [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; ` and it's restoring for me what is bought by other user on the device